# Create footprints on flexible PCB

Tags: pcb-design, footprint, flexible, circuitmaker

I'm completely new to PCB design but I'm trying to create my own flexible PCB. Now I want to recreate the board below but with different contact pads on the bottom (because they are really fragile). Now I've downloaded Fusion 360 and circuitmaker and I've watched some tutorials. But I can't really figure out how to start on this project since there really are no components (only footprints). How would I start to make these footprints?

Update:
So I'm trying to create footprints now. I added a pin and now I'm trying to outline the footprint courtyard to the correct dimensions of the pads. Is this what I should be doing or am I in the wrong direction? And is the big yellow circle the small hole that's in the middle of the pads?
[image]

[image]

Or should I simply create a rectangle pad with a small hole in it, and that's it? I'm not sure what all the other properties are, but this seems correct
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a few ways, you could create each pad as a one pin component and then add it to the schematic. Or you could create one components with multiple pins that correspond to each pad and then add it as one component. You would want to have the correct dimensions for each pad. The pads need to be on the correct layer (toplayer)

The through holes (looks like on the top pads) need to have the correct drill dimension with a rectangular pad.

Once you create the components add them to the schematic and then route the wires to the appropriate pads. After that you need to do the PCB routing. It looks like this is a two layer flex so you could use the same tutorials to route a two layer board. When you go to manufacture it make sure you order a flex the manufacturer should be able take the files for two layer board and create a two layer flex from it. Make sure you also tell them what thinkness you need for the flex. Another thing you need to worry about is if you want the copper vias covered by the coverlay (outside layers of the flex).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response! Would this be easy doable in circuitmaker or do you suggest another program?

Comment: I would prefer kicad, eagle or a free trial of circuitstudio

Comment: I downloaded kicad and I'm trying to follow your instructions. I've updated my question for some follow up questions :)

Comment: I can't give you a detailed walkthrough for kicad. I would suggest going through at least two tutorials: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/beginners-guide-to-kicad https://www.build-electronic-circuits.com/kicad-tutorial/ and then develop your board